# comparing two lists but then saying how many times an item in a list matched

Tags: python, list, numbers, comparison

I am trying to compare `winning_numbers` against the larger list of `previous_winners` then get the count of how many times a certain number turned up.

```
winning_numbers = [20, 49, 47, 40, 36, 4, 2]
previous_winners = [
    [1, 8, 11, 25, 28, 4, 6],
    [13, 16, 34, 35, 45, 10, 12],
    [4, 5, 8, 31, 43, 2, 9],
    [2, 12, 15, 34, 50, 3, 4]
]
```

I have been trying the following

```
compare = set(winning_numbers) & set(previous_winners)
print(compare)
```

But it gives the ERROR `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` unless I use a single list on `previous_winners` which gives for example `{4, 2}` BUT...how can I give the count of how many times those numbers showed up in the `previous_winners` list?

I would like to end up printing out something like 'we match 4 and it was matched 8 times' etc

Comment: So you want to count how many times does 20 appears in previous winners?

Comment: Are you looking for individual counts or does the whole list have to be present in `previous_winners`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flatten the `previous_winners` list and use `collections.Counter` to count the number of occurrences of each number, so that you can iterate through `winning_numbers` to produce a mapping of winning numbers to their counts in `previous_winner`:

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(n for l in previous_winners for n in l)
print({n: counts.get(n, 0) for n in winning_numbers})
```

This outputs:

```
{20: 0, 49: 0, 47: 0, 40: 0, 36: 0, 4: 3, 2: 2}
```

Or if you only want numbers that did appear previously, it would be slightly more efficient to make `winning_numbers` a set first and produce counts from `previous_winners` only for those numbers that are in the set:

```
from collections import Counter
winning_set = set(winning_numbers)
print(Counter(n for l in previous_winners for n in l if n in winning_set))
```

This outputs:

```
Counter({4: 3, 2: 2})
```

Comment: This has got what I need. Thank you for your help I never knew about collections and counter...thank you for highlighting that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) to flatten `previous_winners` and create a dictionary with a `list comprehension` and using [`.count`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_count.htm) to count each occurrence in `previous_winners`:

```
l = list(chain.from_iterable(previous_winners))
{i:l.count(i) for i in winning_numbers}
{20: 0, 49: 0, 47: 0, 40: 0, 36: 0, 4: 3, 2: 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through each list of `previous_winners` and call the intersection of sets, then go through each intersection of `compare` and count up each time a match was found into a dict.

```
matches = {}
for prev in previous_winners:
    compare = set(winning_numbers) & set(prev)
    for match in compare:
        matches[match] = matches.get(match, 0) + 1

for k, v in matches.items():
    print(k, 'occurred', v, 'times')
```

Output:

```
4 occurred 3 times
2 occurred 2 times
```